# How can I use React Router v6 to pass state from a parent route to a child route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to build a page with tabs on it. I'd like each tab to be it's own route.

```js
/project/:id/a
/project/:id/b
/project/:id/c
```

I create my router in my `<App />` component.

**App.tsx**

```js
import { createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import { PageProject } from './pages/PageProject';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/project/:id?/:tab?',
    element: <PageProject />,
  },
]);
```

This works but I have some state *in* my `<PageProject />` component that I want to pass down to each tab component, so rather than define `children` routes in App.tsx, I am trying to define them *within* `<PageProject>`.

**PageProject.tsx**

```js
import { Link, Route, Routes, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

import { PanelA } from './PanelA';
import { PanelB } from './PanelB';
import { PanelC } from './PanelC';

export const PageProject = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [project, setProject] = useState(null);

  // project is fetched from an API using the "id" param and set in state

  return (
    <section>
      <div className="tabs">
        <Link to={`/project/${id}/a">A</Link>
        <Link to={`/project/${id}/b">B</Link>
        <Link to={`/project/${id}/c">C</Link>
      </div>

      <div className="panels">
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<PanelA project={project} />} path={`/project/${id}/a`} />
          <Route element={<PanelB project={project} />} path={`/project/${id}/b`} />
          <Route element={<PanelC project={project} />} path={`/project/${id}/c`} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. Is there a way I can pass state *from a parent component to a child component*?

Comment: The code looks fine to me, `project` prop is passed to each routed component. Can you [edit] to clarify what exactly isn't working as expected, what the specific problem is? See [mcve]. BTW, RRDv6 can use *relative* routing, so you can drop the `"/project/${a}/"` prefix on all the links and routes in `PageProject`, e.g. use just `to="a"` and `path="a"`, etc, no need to manage this manually yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the official way of doing this is using an `<Outlet>` component, provided by `react-router-dom`, that passes `context` to all child routes.

https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-outlet-context

The child routes are defined along side all of the other routes.

**App.tsx**

```js
import { PanelA } from './PanelA';

const App = () => {
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: '/project/:id?',
      element: <PageProject />,
      children: [
        {
          element: <PanelA />
          index: true
        },
        {
          element: <PanelA />
          path: 'a'
        }
      ]
    },
  ]);
}
```

*Note that I removed my `:tab?` parameter, as that segment is now defined as a path. I also added `<PanelA>` two times - once as the `index` component - the default component rendered on the parent - and then again where the `path` is defined explicitly.*

**PageProject.tsx**

```js
import { Project } from '@types';

import { Link, Outlet, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export const PageProject = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [project, setProject] = useState<Project | null>(null);

  // project is fetched from an API using the "id" param and set in state

  return (
    <section>
      <div className="tabs">
        <Link to={`/project/${id}/a">A</Link>
        <Link to={`/project/${id}/b">B</Link>
        <Link to={`/project/${id}/c">C</Link>
      </div>

      <div className="panels">
        <Outlet context={{ project }} />
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Then the child routes can access the `context` using `useOutletContext()`.

**PanelA.tsx**

```js
import { Project } from '@types';

import { useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';

export interface OutletProps {
  project: Project;
}

export const PanelA = () => {
  const { project }: OutletProps = useOutletContext();

  return (
    <div>{project.id}</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The `Outlet` context aren't props though, but this will certainly work for passing values down to nested route components. I still don't see any issue with the way you passed props in the code you were originally trying to use though.